# How to add data entered by the user to a pandas data frame column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'type': ['train', 'train', 'train', 'pool', 'pool', 
'pool', 'pool', 'pool'], 'index': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 'corpus': 
['a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], 'labels': [[1,0,0], 
[0,1,0], [1,1,0], None , None , None  , None , None]}


data = pd.DataFrame(data)

data
```

what I want to do is to display the data from columns "corpus" associated with column 'type' 'pool' to a user add some labels to it. After that, my program should be able insert in the dataset the labels added by the user to each of the texts displayed. With the code below, the program is adding the last label entered by the user and replacing all the labels of the original dataset.

```
for row, c in data.iterrows():
  if c['type'] == 'pool':
    a = input(f"Please enter your labels for 
the below text: \n\n {c['corpus']}")
    data['labels'] = a
```

So, my output current output is:

```
        type     corpus labels
   0    train       a   0,0,1
   1    train       b   0,0,1
   2    train       c   0,0,1
   7    pool        h   0,0,1
   4    pool        e   0,0,1
   3    pool        d   0,0,1
   5    pool        f   0,0,1
   6    pool        g   0,0,1
```

my goal is:

```
    type    corpus   labels
0   train       a   [1, 0, 0]
1   train       b   [0, 1, 0]
2   train       c   [1, 1, 0]
7   pool        h   [1, 0, 0]
4   pool        e   [0, 0, 1]
3   pool        d   [1, 1, 1]
5   pool        f   [0, 1, 0]
6   pool        g   [0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: What is your current code? Please provide a fully working minimal reproducible example

Comment: @MatteoZanoni, I have added my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to fix with the code:

Firstly  if you assign `a` to `data['labels']` you are actually assigning it to the whole column (this is why you get the same value in all rows).

Secondly assigning the return from `input` will assign a string but the other rows contained a list of ints. To solve this we can use `split` to get the elements, map `int` to those and assing using `df.at`

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "type": ["train", "train", "train", "pool", "pool", "pool", "pool", "pool"],
    "index": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    "corpus": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"],
    "labels": [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], None, None, None, None, None],
}


data = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(data)

for idx, row in data.iterrows():
    if row["type"] == "pool":
        a = input(f"Please enter your labels for the below text: \n\n {row['corpus']} ")
        data.at[idx, "labels"] = list(map(int, a.split(",")))
print(data)
```